# Magento2: Magento\Framework\Exception\LocalizedException

Tags: magento2

In exception .log file I have found issue:

Something went wrong while saving files

```
[2018-10-31 10:42:53] main.CRITICAL: Magento\Framework\Exception\LocalizedException: Coś się zepsuło podczas zapisywania plików. in /home/b2b/domains/b2bstyle.pl/public_html/vendor/magento/module-catalog/Model/ImageUploader.php:205
Stack trace:
#0 /home/b2b/domains/b2bstyle.pl/public_html/vendor/magento/module-catalog/Model/Category/Attribute/Backend/Image.php(138): Magento\Catalog\Model\ImageUploader->moveFileFromTmp('BANNERREADY.png')
#1 /home/b2b/domains/b2bstyle.pl/public_html/var/generation/Magento/Catalog/Model/Category/Attribute/Backend/Image/Interceptor.php(37): Magento\Catalog\Model\Category\Attribute\Backend\Image->afterSave(Object(MGS\Mpanel\Model\Category\Interceptor))
#2 [internal function]: Magento\Catalog\Model\Category\Attribute\Backend\Image\Interceptor->afterSave(Object(MGS\Mpanel\Model\Category\Interceptor))
#3 /home/b2b/domains/b2bstyle.pl/public_html/vendor/magento/module-eav/Model/Entity/AbstractEntity.php(689): call_user_func_array(Array, Array)
#4 /home/b2b/domains/b2bstyle.pl/public_html/var/generation/Magento/Catalog/Model/ResourceModel/Category/Interceptor.php(609): Magento\Eav\Model\Entity\AbstractEntity->walkAttributes('backend/afterSa...', Array, NULL)
#5 /home/b2b/domains/b2bstyle.pl/public_html/vendor/magento/module-eav/Model/Entity/AbstractEntity.php(1836): Magento\Catalog\Model\ResourceModel\Category\Interceptor->walkAttributes('backend/afterSa...', Array)
#6 /home/b2b/domains/b2bstyle.pl/public_html/vendor/magento/module-catalog/Model/ResourceModel/Category.php(294): Magento\Eav\Model\Entity\AbstractEntity->_afterSave(Object(MGS\Mpanel\Model\Category\Interceptor))
#7 /home/b2b/domains/b2bstyle.pl/public_html/vendor/magento/module-eav/Model/Entity/AbstractEntity.php(1951): Magento\Catalog\Model\ResourceModel\Category->_afterSave(Object(MGS\Mpanel\Model\Category\Interceptor))
#8 /home/b2b/domains/b2bstyle.pl/public_html/var/generation/Magento/Catalog/Model/ResourceModel/Category/Interceptor.php(843): Magento\Eav\Model\Entity\AbstractEntity->afterSave(Object(MGS\Mpanel\Model\Category\Interceptor))
#9 /home/b2b/domains/b2bstyle.pl/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/EntityManager/Observer/AfterEntitySave.php(33): Magento\Catalog\Model\ResourceModel\Category\Interceptor->afterSave(Object(MGS\Mpanel\Model\Category\Interceptor))
#10 /home/b2b/domains/b2bstyle.pl/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/Event/Invoker/InvokerDefault.php(73): Magento\Framework\EntityManager\Observer\AfterEntitySave->execute(Object(Magento\Framework\Event\Observer))
#11 /home/b2b/domains/b2bstyle.pl/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/Event/Invoker/InvokerDefault.php(61): Magento\Framework\Event\Invoker\InvokerDefault->_callObserverMethod(Object(Magento\Framework\EntityManager\Observer\AfterEntitySave), Object(Magento\Framework\Event\Observer))
#12 /home/b2b/domains/b2bstyle.pl/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/Event/Manager.php(66): Magento\Framework\Event\Invoker\InvokerDefault->dispatch(Array, Object(Magento\Framework\Event\Observer))
#13 /home/b2b/domains/b2bstyle.pl/public_html/var/generation/Magento/Framework/Event/Manager/Proxy.php(95): Magento\Framework\Event\Manager->dispatch('magento_catalog...', Array)
#14 /home/b2b/domains/b2bstyle.pl/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/EntityManager/EventManager.php(52): Magento\Framework\Event\Manager\Proxy->dispatch('magento_catalog...', Array)
#15 /home/b2b/domains/b2bstyle.pl/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/EntityManager/Operation/Update.php(108): Magento\Framework\EntityManager\EventManager->dispatchEntityEvent('Magento\\Catalog...', 'save_after', Array)
#16 /home/b2b/domains/b2bstyle.pl/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/EntityManager/EntityManager.php(87): Magento\Framework\EntityManager\Operation\Update->execute(Object(MGS\Mpanel\Model\Category\Interceptor), Array)
#17 /home/b2b/domains/b2bstyle.pl/public_html/vendor/magento/module-catalog/Model/ResourceModel/Category.php(1052): Magento\Framework\EntityManager\EntityManager->save(Object(MGS\Mpanel\Model\Category\Interceptor))
#18 /home/b2b/domains/b2bstyle.pl/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php(74): Magento\Catalog\Model\ResourceModel\Category->save(Object(MGS\Mpanel\Model\Category\Interceptor))
#19 /home/b2b/domains/b2bstyle.pl/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Chain/Chain.php(70): Magento\Catalog\Model\ResourceModel\Category\Interceptor->___callParent('save', Array)
#20 /home/b2b/domains/b2bstyle.pl/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Chain/Chain.php(63): Magento\Framework\Interception\Chain\Chain->invokeNext('Magento\\Catalog...', 'save', Object(Magento\Catalog\Model\ResourceModel\Category\Interceptor), Array, 'catalogsearchFu...')
#21 /home/b2b/domains/b2bstyle.pl/public_html/vendor/magento/module-catalog-search/Model/Indexer/Fulltext/Plugin/Category.php(43): Magento\Framework\Interception\Chain\Chain->Magento\Framework\Interception\Chain\{closure}(Object(MGS\Mpanel\Model\Category\Interceptor))
#22 /home/b2b/domains/b2bstyle.pl/public_html/vendor/magento/module-catalog-search/Model/Indexer/Fulltext/Plugin/Category.php(29): Magento\CatalogSearch\Model\Indexer\Fulltext\Plugin\Category->addCommitCallback(Object(Magento\Catalog\Model\ResourceModel\Category\Interceptor), Object(Closure), Object(MGS\Mpanel\Model\Category\Interceptor))
#23 /home/b2b/domains/b2bstyle.pl/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Chain/Chain.php(67): Magento\CatalogSearch\Model\Indexer\Fulltext\Plugin\Category->aroundSave(Object(Magento\Catalog\Model\ResourceModel\Category\Interceptor), Object(Closure), Object(MGS\Mpanel\Model\Category\Interceptor))
#24 /home/b2b/domains/b2bstyle.pl/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php(138): Magento\Framework\Interception\Chain\Chain->invokeNext('Magento\\Catalog...', 'save', Object(Magento\Catalog\Model\ResourceModel\Category\Interceptor), Array, 'clean_cache')
#25 /home/b2b/domains/b2bstyle.pl/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/App/Cache/FlushCacheByTags.php(71): Magento\Catalog\Model\ResourceModel\Category\Interceptor->Magento\Framework\Interception\{closure}(Object(MGS\Mpanel\Model\Category\Interceptor))
#26 /home/b2b/domains/b2bstyle.pl/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php(142): Magento\Framework\App\Cache\FlushCacheByTags->aroundSave(Object(Magento\Catalog\Model\ResourceModel\Category\Interceptor), Object(Closure), Object(MGS\Mpanel\Model\Category\Interceptor))
#27 /home/b2b/domains/b2bstyle.pl/public_html/var/generation/Magento/Catalog/Model/ResourceModel/Category/Interceptor.php(364): Magento\Catalog\Model\ResourceModel\Category\Interceptor->___callPlugins('save', Array, Array)
#28 /home/b2b/domains/b2bstyle.pl/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/Model/AbstractModel.php(636): Magento\Catalog\Model\ResourceModel\Category\Interceptor->save(Object(MGS\Mpanel\Model\Category\Interceptor))
#29 /home/b2b/domains/b2bstyle.pl/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php(146): Magento\Framework\Model\AbstractModel->save()
#30 /home/b2b/domains/b2bstyle.pl/public_html/var/generation/MGS/Mpanel/Model/Category/Interceptor.php(1547): MGS\Mpanel\Model\Category\Interceptor->___callPlugins('save', Array, Array)
#31 /home/b2b/domains/b2bstyle.pl/public_html/vendor/magento/module-catalog/Model/CategoryLinkRepository.php(47): MGS\Mpanel\Model\Category\Interceptor->save()
#32 /home/b2b/domains/b2bstyle.pl/public_html/vendor/magento/module-catalog/Model/CategoryLinkManagement.php(105): Magento\Catalog\Model\CategoryLinkRepository->save(Object(Magento\Catalog\Model\CategoryProductLink))
#33 /home/b2b/domains/b2bstyle.pl/public_html/app/code/Yosto/Mpa/Controller/Adminhtml/Product/MassCategory.php(148): Magento\Catalog\Model\CategoryLinkManagement->assignProductToCategories('TRIDENT_90_S_C7...', Array)
#34 /home/b2b/domains/b2bstyle.pl/public_html/var/generation/Yosto/Mpa/Controller/Adminhtml/Product/MassCategory/Interceptor.php(37): Yosto\Mpa\Controller\Adminhtml\Product\MassCategory->assignCategories(Object(Magento\Catalog\Model\ResourceModel\Product\Collection\Interceptor), Array, Array)
#35 /home/b2b/domains/b2bstyle.pl/public_html/app/code/Yosto/Mpa/Controller/Adminhtml/Product/MassCategory.php(112): Yosto\Mpa\Controller\Adminhtml\Product\MassCategory\Interceptor->assignCategories(Object(Magento\Catalog\Model\ResourceModel\Product\Collection\Interceptor), Array, Array)
#36 /home/b2b/domains/b2bstyle.pl/public_html/var/generation/Yosto/Mpa/Controller/Adminhtml/Product/MassCategory/Interceptor.php(24): Yosto\Mpa\Controller\Adminhtml\Product\MassCategory->execute()
#37 /home/b2b/domains/b2bstyle.pl/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/App/Action/Action.php(102): Yosto\Mpa\Controller\Adminhtml\Product\MassCategory\Interceptor->execute()
#38 /home/b2b/domains/b2bstyle.pl/public_html/vendor/magento/module-backend/App/AbstractAction.php(226): Magento\Framework\App\Action\Action->dispatch(Object(Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http))
#39 /home/b2b/domains/b2bstyle.pl/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php(74): Magento\Backend\App\AbstractAction->dispatch(Object(Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http))
#40 /home/b2b/domains/b2bstyle.pl/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Chain/Chain.php(70): Yosto\Mpa\Controller\Adminhtml\Product\MassCategory\Interceptor->___callParent('dispatch', Array)
#41 /home/b2b/domains/b2bstyle.pl/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Chain/Chain.php(63): Magento\Framework\Interception\Chain\Chain->invokeNext('Yosto\\Mpa\\Contr...', 'dispatch', Object(Yosto\Mpa\Controller\Adminhtml\Product\MassCategory\Interceptor), Array, 'adminAuthentica...')
#42 /home/b2b/domains/b2bstyle.pl/public_html/vendor/magento/module-backend/App/Action/Plugin/Authentication.php(143): Magento\Framework\Interception\Chain\Chain->Magento\Framework\Interception\Chain\{closure}(Object(Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http))
#43 /home/b2b/domains/b2bstyle.pl/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Chain/Chain.php(67): Magento\Backend\App\Action\Plugin\Authentication->aroundDispatch(Object(Yosto\Mpa\Controller\Adminhtml\Product\MassCategory\Interceptor), Object(Closure), Object(Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http))
#44 /home/b2b/domains/b2bstyle.pl/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php(138): Magento\Framework\Interception\Chain\Chain->invokeNext('Yosto\\Mpa\\Contr...', 'dispatch', Object(Yosto\Mpa\Controller\Adminhtml\Product\MassCategory\Interceptor), Array, 'adminMassaction...')
#45 /home/b2b/domains/b2bstyle.pl/public_html/vendor/magento/module-backend/App/Action/Plugin/MassactionKey.php(33): Yosto\Mpa\Controller\Adminhtml\Product\MassCategory\Interceptor->Magento\Framework\Interception\{closure}(Object(Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http))
#46 /home/b2b/domains/b2bstyle.pl/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php(142): Magento\Backend\App\Action\Plugin\MassactionKey->aroundDispatch(Object(Yosto\Mpa\Controller\Adminhtml\Product\MassCategory\Interceptor), Object(Closure), Object(Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http))
#47 /home/b2b/domains/b2bstyle.pl/public_html/var/generation/Yosto/Mpa/Controller/Adminhtml/Product/MassCategory/Interceptor.php(78): Yosto\Mpa\Controller\Adminhtml\Product\MassCategory\Interceptor->___callPlugins('dispatch', Array, Array)
#48 /home/b2b/domains/b2bstyle.pl/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/App/FrontController.php(55): Yosto\Mpa\Controller\Adminhtml\Product\MassCategory\Interceptor->dispatch(Object(Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http))
#49 /home/b2b/domains/b2bstyle.pl/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php(74): Magento\Framework\App\FrontController->dispatch(Object(Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http))
#50 /home/b2b/domains/b2bstyle.pl/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Chain/Chain.php(70): Magento\Framework\App\FrontController\Interceptor->___callParent('dispatch', Array)
#51 /home/b2b/domains/b2bstyle.pl/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php(138): Magento\Framework\Interception\Chain\Chain->invokeNext('Magento\\Framewo...', 'dispatch', Object(Magento\Framework\App\FrontController\Interceptor), Array, 'install')
#52 /home/b2b/domains/b2bstyle.pl/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/Module/Plugin/DbStatusValidator.php(69): Magento\Framework\App\FrontController\Interceptor->Magento\Framework\Interception\{closure}(Object(Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http))
#53 /home/b2b/domains/b2bstyle.pl/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php(142): Magento\Framework\Module\Plugin\DbStatusValidator->aroundDispatch(Object(Magento\Framework\App\FrontController\Interceptor), Object(Closure), Object(Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http))
#54 /home/b2b/domains/b2bstyle.pl/public_html/var/generation/Magento/Framework/App/FrontController/Interceptor.php(26): Magento\Framework\App\FrontController\Interceptor->___callPlugins('dispatch', Array, Array)
#55 /home/b2b/domains/b2bstyle.pl/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/App/Http.php(135): Magento\Framework\App\FrontController\Interceptor->dispatch(Object(Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http))
#56 /home/b2b/domains/b2bstyle.pl/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/App/Bootstrap.php(258): Magento\Framework\App\Http->launch()
#57 /home/b2b/domains/b2bstyle.pl/public_html/index.php(39): Magento\Framework\App\Bootstrap->run(Object(Magento\Framework\App\Http))
#58 {main} [] []
```

Comment: Can you please upload your file code ?

Comment: from /vendor/magento/module-catalog/Model/ImageUploader.php:205 ?

Comment: Your magento version ? and which extension file you upload ?